# Startup repair failure: Patch is preventing the system from starting, error 0x1F

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update

My Windows 7 machine failed to load after a start up repair failed.

The error message I got was this:

> Root cause found:
>   A patch is preventing the system from starting
>   Error code = 0x1F

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Tony, I would bet that giving your question a much better, more descriptive title will result in more people willing to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error it sounds like a Windows Update has been applied incorrectly.  Your only real hope if you are not a technically savvy person is to run system restore on your computer.  You can do so from the Start up repair utility.